Passing column names as strings do not work with filter() and only with filter()
Given the following dataframe:
df <- data.frame(a=c(NA,1,2), b=c(3,4,5))

I can pass column name as string in select:
> df %>% select("a")
   a
1 NA
2  1
3  2

Or I can use symbolic names with select. That's fine too:
> df %>% select(a)
   a
1 NA
2  1
3  2

pull accepts both as well:
> df %>% pull("a")
[1] NA  1  2
> df %>% pull(a)
[1] NA  1  2

But I cannot use strings with filter:
> df %>% filter("a"==1)
[1] a b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

only symbolic names:
> df %>% filter(a==1)
  a b
1 1 4

Why it works with select but not with filter?
Shouldn't it be consistent?

Not really. filter expects a logical expression ("a"==1 returns FALSE) while select uses  expressions, which have some degree of flexibility.

The case is not exactly the same. In select you provide the name of a column (be it a string or a symbol). In filter you provide and expression. How would it make the difference between a=="b" (the column a is equal to the string "b") and a=="b" (the column a is equal to the column "b" ?

@Billy34 oh I see

You said: "But I cannot use strings with filter". Oh, but you can! You get a data frame with 0 rows.

OP's questions are "Why it works with select but not with filter? Shouldn't it be consistent?" None of the answer adress the questions.

@Edward I think you should turn that into an answer

"a" is an argument to select and pull but is not an argument to filter so the situations are not the same. Also the code shown here which returns rows for which column a equals the letter "a" would  no longer work if it were allowed to interpret "a" as column a.
data.frame(a = letters) %>% filter( a == "a" )
##   a
## 1 a

1) dplyr provides if_any and if_all
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(if_any("a") == 1)
##   a b
## 1 1 4

2) Although filter_at has been superseded by the syntax in (1), superseded is not the same as deprecated and it will continue to be available so it is ok to use it though not preferred by the dplyr developers.
df %>%
  filter_at("a", all_vars(. == 1))
##   a b
## 1 1 4

Also note that this used to work and actually still does with a warning but in the future it will not work at all as it has been deprecated so do not use:
# deprecated - do not use
df %>%
  filter(across("a", ~ . == 1))

Note
Input from question
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, 1, 2), b = c(3, 4, 5))


You could use
df %>%
  filter(get("a") == 1)


You can use rlang
df %>% 
  filter(!!rlang::sym('a') == 1)

